# Create the Launch Configuration with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-iam, aws-auto-scaling

I have a problem with building the launch configuration.
I need to make an autoscaling group for the ec2 instance in the subnet,
but the problem that I face with iaminstanceprofile I don't know how to do it.
could anybody help?

```
''' create iam role ...

    response = iam_client.create_role(
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument='\<Stringified-JSON\>',
    Path='/',
    RoleName='asg-Role',
    )
    pprint(response)

'''  A- Create the Launch Configuration '''

response = AS_client.create_launch_configuration(
IamInstanceProfile='asg-Role',
ImageId='ami-06b09bfacae1453cb',
InstanceType='t2.micro',
LaunchConfigurationName='my-launch-config',
SecurityGroups=[
SG_ec2,],
)
pprint(response)
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? Are you receiving an error message? Does your code work? What do you mean by "I don't know how to do it" -- what is 'it'?

Comment: thanks a lot, I actually did it my problem was in creating IamInstanceProfile to clarify more if someone has the same problem first begin with creating a policy for autoscaling then create the ec2fullacsses permission to do it, if you have any recommendations i am all ears .

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation is not easy to understand. Could you please clarify what recommendation are you seeking? Feel free to Edit your question to clarify the details.

Comment: I was facing a problem creating  IamInstanceProfile for the autoscaling group which I can't find it in boto3 documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have having difficulty creating the instance profile, you can:

- Use [`create_instance_profile()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_instance_profile) to create Instance Profile object, then
- Use [`add_role_to_instance_profile()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.add_role_to_instance_profile) to add an IAM Role to the Instance Profile

Then, when calling `create_launch_configuration()`, you can pass the Name or ARN of the Instance Profile that was created.